# Install bootstrap 5 with bootstrap 4 color scheme

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap changed some colors schemes from 4 to 5.

Is there any way to install bootstrap 5 and keep the original colors of boostrap 4 without having to manually change the files?

Is there any cdn that has this styles?

Comment: See if it helps https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/ you can always overwrite color with custom CSS to same class

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that are any cdns or versions to install that have this styles.

What I did is manually override the styles. This [Link](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203) gives out instructions on how to do it, as well as how to use SASS for more extensive Bootstrap customizations.